# Is there any Android emulator toolkit for testing?

Tags: android, testing, emulation

Is there any Android emulators for testing like Sprint Toolkit, Sun java toolkit?

I need to test my android application. How to test the android application?

Comment: Eh.Android SDK includes the simulator, doesn't it?http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: hmmmm right. but im asking about separate toolbar. like Sprint toolkit. This toolkit contains lot of mobile simulators and we can test easily on different type of mobiles. Im asking like that on android..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create different android emulator images that mimic the different hardware and software features of the devices available. Like said above there are some available from the manufacturers for download (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab, B&N Nook Color, Cisco Cius, Motorola and so on) and with a bit of googling you can create ones for other devices easily as well. All you need is the phones datasheet.

For actual hardware testing there are things like Device Anywhere.

For running test suites look at Robotium, Roboelectric or the SDK provided Monkeyrunner.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no such thing available. But some third parties are providing AVDs for Android Development Tool such as Samsung has recently provided for the Galaxy Tab. So you can use emulator for virtually any device.

Answer (score 2):

Android has already the android emulator. You can mimic any type of phone you plan to ship your app to by changing the various configurations when creating an AVD.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across something close to this a while back. The name was [Device Anywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/). I thought they had a demo video online that showcases it, but it appears they have removed it. You could sign up for a free demo, however.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MOTODEV Studio for Android](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/). What I remember from droidcon is it contains several different emulator configurations (AVDs) representing available Motorola devices. Although I believe the underlying emulator guts are exactly the same as Android SDK and AVD Manager.